# Upload whole folder structure in Amazon s3 bucket using powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3

I am in process to automate upload my static files to Amazon s3 bucket. My folder structure is bit complex as it contain lods of folders with sub folders and files.

Is there any easy way to upload the parent folder to s3 bucket instead looping through all folder, create them of S3 bucket and then upload the files in folders?

I want to do this though powershell.

Comment: how about ncftpput with a recurse option?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to install the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which is available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Then, from PowerShell, call the `aws s3 sync` command, which can **recursively replicate a folder** to/from Amazon S3 (and even between S3 buckets).

See: [aws s3 sync documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method (powershell)

First enter "Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Installer" to get the right packages

then you can run the following script

```
Set-AWSCredential `
             -AccessKey "yourkey" `
             -SecretKey "yoursecret" `
             -StoreAs default

Write-S3Object -BucketName "mystuff" -Folder "c:\test\images" -KeyPrefix "dec25\"
```

The Keyprefix is optional, everything will be written under that path in your bucket

See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Write-S3Object.html
There are recursive options for subfolders and whatnot